# Npm ERR! Invalid version on npm install

Tags: npm, version

Whenever I run npm install I get

```
npm ERR! Invalid Version:
```

This is the log file.

```
43 verbose stack TypeError: Invalid Version: 
43 verbose stack     at new SemVer (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\classes\semver.js:38:13)
43 verbose stack     at compare (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\functions\compare.js:3:32)
43 verbose stack     at Object.gte (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\functions\gte.js:2:30)
43 verbose stack     at Node.canDedupe (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\node.js:1054:32)
43 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.pruneDedupable (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:465:14)
43 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.placeInTree (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:326:14)
43 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.place (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:214:10)
43 verbose stack     at new PlaceDep (C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:71:10)
43 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:965:31
43 verbose stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
44 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dont\Want\To\Reveal\This\Information
45 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
46 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Myself\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-force"
47 verbose node v16.14.0
48 verbose npm  v8.5.1
49 error Invalid Version: 
50 verbose exit 1
51 timing npm Completed in 18500ms
```

I don't understand what version of what is invalid? Help!

Comment: It would help if you would provide your `package.json`.
Either the whole file – or _at least_ `"version": "x.x.x"` **and**
_everything_ under `"dependencies"`.

Answer (score 41):

Deleting`node_modules` and `package-lock.json (OR yarn.lock)` solved the issue for me.

Comment: thx! Sometimes you just wanna make it work without digging deeper and trying to understand all the nuances about npm.

Comment: thanks, just deleting the package.lock worked for me.

Comment: OK, it works to delete the package-lock.json, the question is why? How to know where the error comes from?
I am getting `error Invalid Version: ^5.0.0` in an Angular 13 app. But why? Which package? I don't see it in the logs. Must be this in package.json: `"resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }`

Comment: If you don't want to delete your lock file: Open the lock file, and delete all occurrences of the package npm complains about. Save the lock file and run `npm install` again.

Comment: rm -f node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force

Comment: Anyone find the root solution for this? If this is happening in the pipeline where its a fresh install each time, none of these solutions work.

Comment: still having this issue though i tried cleaning the cach, removing npm modules, the .lock files, nothing worked ... " npm ERR! Invalid Version: 3.5.0pr2 " this is the error now

Answer (score 10):

Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/.package-lock.json`, then run the `npm install` command again.

This solves the problem for me without having to delete and re-download all the modules that were installed correctly.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. I didn't have to delete the whole node_modules folder

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Delete the node_modules folder, remove package.lock and clean cache:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package.json.lock
npm cache clean
```

If you want to run the risk of breaking changes (not recommended)

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Re-install

```
npm install
```

or simply

```
npm i
```

Comment: I would like to ask why this works.

Comment: rm -f node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force

Comment: deleting the lock file is not recommended, you may unintentionally break something

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with npm@8.12. Fixed by downgrading to npm@8.5.

Comment: Actually you upgraded the npm version not downgrade it.

Comment: @SaeedHemmati 8.5 is lower than 8.12.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**
if you check your "package.json" file in your projects root, it's probably missing one or all of the following properties:

1. name
2. version

for version, it has to be in the form "x.x.x", i.e in my(and probably yours) case "1.0.0"

for name you can obtain it from the "app.json" for example in my case:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                   
     "expo": {
       "name": "the-10-min",
       "slug": "the-10-min",
       "privacy": "public",
       "platforms": [
         "ios",
         "android",
         "web"
      ],
```

so in my case the name property in the "package.json" file will be "the-10-min"
.Plug in the values for name and version then run the command "npm install"

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "version" key from your package.json file.

For example, your package.json may look like this:

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  // rest of file
}
```

Remove the "version" line so it becomes:

```
{
  "name": "app_name", 
  "private": true,
  // rest of file
}
```

Removing the version number forces npm to use the latest available version of each dependency instead of trying to install a specific one. This can resolve errors where npm tries to install an invalid or unavailable version.

Let me know if the error persists after removing the version number, as there could be other causes. But this solution works for me.

Comment: @Yunnosch got it <>

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to edit my answr will do it right now

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and tips on improving my answer! I have updated my answer to follow the formatting guidelines better and provide more clarity. Please see the revised version @Yunnosch

Answer (score 0):

You should also ensure that the name properties in app.json and package.json are the same- they were different in mine and caused the error

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem after cloning an old project. Tried all of these solutions, none worked. Turns out my problem was due to deprecated package versions. I removed them all and added them gradually until I figured out which were the ones giving me problems. Luckily, The newer versions of these packages were ok.